# select all except few nodes by xpath

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

Just little help. Please let me know the correct xpath expression for this

I have xml doc like this

```
<parent>
                    <child id='1' show='true' />
                    <child id='2' show='true' />
                    <child id='3' show='true' />
                    <child id='4' show='true' />
                    <child id='5' show='true' />
                    <child id='6' show='true' />
                </parent>
```

I want to select all `show` attributes except 2nd and 5th childs so that i can turn their values to `false`

Comment: I would say the smart expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean `and` in your XPath expression:

```
/parent/child[@id != '2' and @id != '5']
```

If you really want the second and fifth element, you can use the `position()` function:

```
/parent/child[position() != 2 and position() != 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[not(position() = 2 or position() = 5)]/@show
```

This selects any `show` attribute of any child of the top element of the xml document, that isn't the second or the fifth child of its parent.